# Remote profile winforms application VS2012 Pro

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, profiler

Is it possible to profile an application running on a remote host using VS2012 Pro? If so, how?

I've followed the instructions on various guides eg: [link to msdn guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anilchandra/archive/2012/09/24/test.aspx) to no avail. When I try to launch the profiler I get this screen (when running locally I can select the project from this dialog): [image]

I'm able to remotely debug both by launching the app remotely from within VS and by attaching to the process on the remote host.

Comment: Remote debugging works by actually running the debugger on the remote machine.  Msvsmon.exe gets that job done.  But no, Microsoft never wrote a similar helper process for the profiler.  Probably because of the rather massive amount of data that a profiler generates, what makes it go catatonic for a while after the profiled app terminates.  You can stop looking, it does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, I think it would be useful for others to make this an answer as there seems to be many conflicting answers to this, hence me asking. Are there alternative tools to remotely track memory? I'm wondering how others deal with this? Thanks.